# Configuring propel return type for flex

Tags: php, apache-flex, propel

I use wamp server and Propel.I have written my service using Propel but when I want to connect the data returned from the service Flex cannot recognize the return type.

This  is the php code that I wrote

```
<?php 

// Include the main Propel script
require_once 'C:/wamp/propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php';

// Initialize Propel with the runtime configuration
Propel::init("C:/wamp/www/school/build/conf/school-conf.php");

// Add the generated 'classes' directory to the include path
set_include_path("C:/wamp/www/school/build/classes" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

class TeacherService { 
function getTeachers()
{

 $allTeachers=TeacherQuery::create()->find();

 $teachers=array();
 foreach($allTeachers as $teacher1)
 {

  array_push($teachers, $teacher1); 

 }

return $teachers;
}
}
?>
```

I wanto to display the information of teacers in a datagrid yet when I choose to auto-detect the return type it gives the error

```
'teacher' cannot be set to the data type "StdClass" because it has no properties.
```

How can I let flex know the properties of teacher rows returned by propel?

Comment: I added the PHP Tag b/c you seem to only provide PHP code.  I, personally, don't know what propel is.

Answer (score 0):

@www.Flextras.com
Propel is a PHP ORM framework.

If you want serialization to work on your php class you would have to have something like this

```
var $_explicitType = "path.to.classes.Teacher";
```

and on your Flex side VO's you would have to have something like this.

```
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="path.to.classes.Teacher")]
```

This is assuming you are using AMF.  Also in your AMF endpoint you have to specify the mapping, so for example I would have something like this in my endpoint file.

```
$server->setClassMap('path.to.classes.Teacher' , 'path\to\classes\Teacher');
```

This lets your endpoint know that when it sees a class with the matching descriptor, which class on the PHP side it should be deserialized to.